# Detecting sparse bit patterns

Tags: bit, sparse-matrix

If I have two 32-bit integers, what's the best way to detect which among them has dense/sparse bit distribution? For example, 0xef00 and 0x1131. Wondering if there are any metrics/transformation that can tell me to choose the latter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible metric:

```
sparseness = popcnt((x<<2) | (x<<1) | x | (x>>1) | (x>>2)) / popcnt(x)
```

sparseness = 1 .. 3 for dense bit distribution, sparseness = 3 .. 5 for sparse bit distribution.

You can use a different number of shifts and/or use bit rotations instead of shifts.